# How do I merge an existing git repository into an empty one and preserve the history?

Tags: git, repository, github

I have a project that I've been working on called "system" that I set up as a repo. I've been pulling and pushing to the project (system.git).

Now I want to publish it to a site like github.  What is the best way to take my current project and push it into the new github project without losing my history?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create the repo on Github.

Then you will set the origin to that project

```
git remote add origin [git hub url]
```

Then do a:

```
git push origin [branch name]
```

And you will push your local repository to Github (with all history etc)

Comment: Thanks for the start ghills. I had to do a "git remote rm origin" first, then I could change it. I then had to do a "git pull origin master" to merge the master branch. Then I could do the "git push origin master".  Awesome! Again, thanks!

Comment: You could've actually force push it by `git push [git hub url] +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`

Comment: Or "git push origin --all --tags" to push all branches and tags.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a reply to hacker's comment on the answer from ghills, but it got a bit long, and SO didn't like me putting a bunch of code in a comment.

...or you could use a name other than "origin".  For instance, I have a repository in which my "master" branch pushes to one github repo, and the "hacking" branch pushes to another.

In .git/config, I have this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:xiongchiamiov/fourU.git
[branch "hacking"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/hacking
[remote "main"]
    url = git@github.com:xyztextbooks/fourU.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/main/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = main
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://gist.github.com/142803) is also useful for managing tracking of remote branches.