# Combine several Git repositories into one (with subfolders) and preserve individual file history

Tags: git, git-merge, subtree, filter-repo

I am trying to combine several Git repositories into one.
I have the folowing individual repositories:

```
-mainrepo
-repo1
  |-src
  |-pom.xml
-repo2
  |-src
  |-pom.xml
-repo3
  |-src
  |-pom.xml
```

I want to combine them into the folowing structure in mainrepo:

```
-mainrepo
  |-repo1
     |-src
     |-pom.xml
  |-repo2
     |-src
     |-pom.xml
  |-repo3
     |-src
     |-pom.xml
```

I have tried git subtree to copy the content of subdirectories:

```
git subtree add --prefix=repo1 https://bitbucket.org/repos/repo1.git master
```

and then tried to rewrite the history with git filter-repo:

```
git filter-repo --force --path src/ --path pom.xml --path-rename :repo1/
```

This approach works, but only for the first repository. When I try to do the same steps to add the second reposity, the history for the firts one vanishes:

```
git subtree add --prefix=repo2 https://bitbucket.org/repos/repo2.git master
git filter-repo --force --path src/ --path pom.xml --path-rename :repo2/
```

I have tried the approach from [How to merge N git repositories into one preserving their histories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319673/how-to-merge-n-git-repositories-into-one-preserving-their-histories) but it doesn't preferve the history of individual files.
Have also tried [Merge two Git repositories without breaking file history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history) with no luck. The history is not available for individual files as well.

Can someone please come up with a better way to do it?

**Edit**

I have found the solution. In fact, it is pretty simple.
First I need to clone every repo (repo1, repo2 ...)
Then I need to rewrite the history in every repo and move the code to the corresponding subfolder with git filter-repo.
Next I need init mainrepo and merge all repos.
So, I need to:

```
mkdir mainrepo
cd mainrepo
git init
cd ..
```

Next, for every repo do the following:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/repos/repo1.git
cd repo1
git filter-repo --path src/ --path pom.xml --to-subdirectory-filter repo1
cd ../mainrepo
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories ../repo1/
cd ..
```

Comment: The 2nd `git filter-repo` must take into account that directory `repo1` already exists; currently it simply removes it, that why you 1st history vanished.

Comment: I thought about it. But how to achieve this result? I didn't find a correct option in git-filter-repo documentation.

Comment: I must say I don't understand what you do with `filter-repo`. `git subtree add --prefix=repo1` pull everything under `repo1`, `git subtree add --prefix=repo2` under `repo2`. Why do you need `git filter-repo` afterwards?

Comment: In order to rewrite the history. git subtree combines the history at the root level, but I would like to have a history on every individual file. if you do git log repo1/pom.xml after subtree, there will be only 1 commit. I am sure that this is not the correct way of achieving what I want, but I haven't found the other way yet.

Comment: Would this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories (see the note about subdirectory). This example seems relevant: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/#simple-example-with-comparisons

Comment: Yes. This is where I started and what, in fact, I tried to use. It works only if I need to combine 2 repositories. If I try to combine more, I end up with the result from my question. When I try to do the same steps to add the second repository, the history for the first one vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

Git submodules are the tool you are looking for.

Their usage is loved by some, hated by others, but they objectively do exactly what you want.

Documentation: [Git - Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules):

> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use another project from within it. Perhaps it’s a library that a third party developed or that you’re developing separately and using in multiple parent projects. A common issue arises in these scenarios: **you want to be able to treat the two projects as separate yet still be able to use one from within the other**.

Comment: As I know, submodules create a link to an external repository. It doesn't copy the data. I am trying to create a separate repository with all the data from other repositories inside, that will not depend on external repositories.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: In order to build it as one multi module project and get rid of multiple repositories that depend on each other.